# Can I use tig to only display a given set of commits

Tags: git, tig

I'd like to use tig to browse an arbitrary list of commits so that I can do something like:

```
git rev-list --author joe | tig --stdin
```

and then *only* see Joe's commits. However, I see one of Joe's commits as the first one, but then other commits too. Even more simply if I did:

```
echo <SHA> | tig --stdin
```

I want to only see that one commit. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tig accepts mostly the same arguments as "git log", so you can do

```
tig <SHA> -1
```

to only show one commit.
Also you can pass a commit range like

```
tig HEAD~10..HEAD
```